# Nginx Cache whole Node/Express Application

Tags: node.js, express, caching, nginx

Jolly goody Morning! I'm trying to fully cache a Node/Express Application. The Site rarely changes, so I'd love to have a pretty string caching mechanism.

How would the Setting look to completely put the application (html, css, img, ...) into the Nginx cache (public Cache) for 5min, so the Page gets served "statically" form the Nginx Cache while the Express-App baiscally idles?

I feel this isn't the right setup here:

```
proxy_cache_path /cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g
                 inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location ^~ / {
                proxy_cache my_cache;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
                }
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't feel right, what do you mean? This setup is identical to the one on [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) blog. If you want to inspect headers, you can add the X-Cache-Status header as seen further down on this page and then you can `curl -I` to inspect the headers.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Hi, thanks for your comment! Do you know the right setup to cache everything, so the actuall Node/Express application is basically not even called anymore? Would love to go from there, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. What you're describing is making your entire site static. If it's speed you're concerned about, then rewrite everything in your node app to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Otherwise, the only way to have your entire site in cache (with this setup) is to visit each page manually and even then it will flush it after an hour.

Answer (score 1):

```
proxy_cache_path /cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:100m max_size=10g inactive=5m use_temp_path=off;
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location ^~ / {
                proxy_cache my_cache;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;                
                # cache all requests of any type for 5m
                proxy_cache_methods HEAD GET POST;
                proxy_cache_valid any 5m;
                expires 5m;
                # default proxy cache key can be adjusted
                proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
                # set header - Host & Forwarded-For
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                # cache on first use
                proxy_cache_min_uses 0;
                }
}
```

[Module ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

- *expire* in ***5 minutes***
- all content is *valid* for ***5 minutes***
- clear *inactive* cache after ***5 minutes***

Keep up to date with [nginx news](https://nginx.org/)